# mysql_query returning a bool?

Tags: php, mysql, database

I am trying to get my server to connect.. But I'm having some trouble.

So, I have this code:

```
$id = (int)$_GET["id"];

$temp = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM ForumThread WHERE ID = $id");
if (mysql_num_rows($temp) > 0) {
    $ThreadInfo = mysql_fetch_assoc($temp);
}
if ($ThreadInfo) {
    if (isset($_GET["p"])-1) {
        $page = $_GET["p"];
    } else {
        $page = 1;
    }
    $offset =( 8 * intval($page));
    if(!$offset){
        $offset = 0;
    }


$posttemp = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM ForumPost WHERE ThreadID = $id ORDER BY ID ASC LIMIT $offset, 9");

$numpost = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ForumPost WHERE ThreadID = $id");
$numpostfin = mysql_result($numpost, 0);
$numpage = ceil($numpostfin / 8);

$ThreadPost = mysql_fetch_assoc($posttemp);
}
```

But when I try this out on my site, it's skipping the first row. Just the first.

So I have this test in my database, and it won't 
where I have:

(I am not allowed to post pictures, because I don't have a reputation of 10)

[My database - Don't mind the danish](http://gyazo.com/89f3c5828a3cb9246b545a09d6a76226)

And its skipping the first that it reads?

Please excuse my English :)

Comment: **Please, [stop using `mysql_*` functions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php).** They are no longer maintained and are [officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). **Learn about [prepared statements](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement)** instead, and **use [PDO](http://us1.php.net/pdo).**

Comment: What's the value of $page (are you starting at page 0 or page 1?)

Comment: `if (isset($_GET["p"])-1) {` ?!? If `isset($_GET["p"])` is TRUE, this will then execute `TRUE - 1` (giving `0` after type-juggling) which will be treated as a FALSE for the `if` statement

Comment: The first call to `mysql_result()` advances the record pointer, which is why it appears to skip a row later.

Comment: are there any errors on display? use `error_reporting(E_ALL);`

Comment: what does (int)$_GET['id']?

Comment: @TopQuestions It casts the input `?id=<something>` to an integer, which would be numeric if it was a numeric value or zero if it was not numeric.

Comment: If you must call `mysql_result()` in that place, you would then need to rewind it after with `mysql_data_seek($numpost, 0)`

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski Thanks. Haven't seen it that way anywhere before...I used to check if(ctype_digit($_GET['id'])) and then escape it...